# Using png icon as drawable in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, icons, png, navigation-drawer

and thanks in advance!

I have trouble changing icons in NavigationDrawer, I'm using a png image as drawable in NavigationDrawer but it causes InflaterException. Can I use png's or Android only accepts XML drawables?

Here is the error, and the code! Any advice will be appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cursos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cursos"
        android:title="Cursos" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Localización" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Contacto" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="animaciones" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/preferencias"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="preferencias" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

```
I have tried placing directly image on drawable, and changing drawables.xml too. Here:

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_cursos" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_cursos</item>
<item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
<item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
<item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
<item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
<item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
```

But it keeps failing. Here the error:

```
Process: com.example.dani.provandodrawer, PID: 28495

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dani.provandodrawer/com.example.dani.provandodrawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.example.dani.provandodrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.dani.provandodrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02007f a=2 r=0x7f02007f}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:147)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:485)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:426)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:113)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:233)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:168)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.example.dani.provandodrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are using android drawables as I see. Just try setting         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_..." in your items. If you want to set a png image, just add the png into drawables folder and set it as android:icon="@drawable/my_image"

Comment: Hola Luis Miguel, gracias por contestar. Lo tengo puesto como dices, solo que sin "android:" delante porque es un recurso mio, no del sistema. Lo curioso es que no he encontrado nada en foros en internet, es raro!

Comment: Por usar imágenes en .png no deberías tener problemas. Prueba a quitar el fichero xml y usar directamente la imagen de la carpeta drawables. Es la única diferencia que veo con lo que suelo hacer. Deberías usar siempre el inglés por aquí

Comment: Hi again, removing drawables.xml generates another error. It's like png is not supported but I can't find references to this issue anywhere.

Comment: Which error? I'm using pngs as icons in some of my projects, so it shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: You have created a drawer with the template that generates you android studio?

Comment: Never used the template.

Answer (score 1):

Well Android only accepts vector icons for the navigation drawer menu. So for you to have your png icon loaded as vector, first convert it to an SVG file using tools such as https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg. After that in Android Studio right-click on your drawable folder and select New, then navigate to Vector Asset. On Asset Type select Local File(SVG, PSD) and put the path of your SVG file and figure out the rest. I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02007f a=2 r=0x7f02007f}
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
```

The error tells that probably the image resources are not placed in drawable folder. Put your images in res/drawable folder of project.

Comment: Hi Tafveez, the image is in the folder... It seems something about compatibility with png, but I think it may be possible!

Answer (score -1):

The best way to use Drawable in navigation, is using the following library...
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer
believe me, it will save you a lot of time.

Edit: here some code example how to use with drawable

```
public class AdvancedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PROFILE_SETTING = 1;

//save our header or result
private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
private Drawer result = null;

private IProfile profile;
private IProfile profile2;
private IProfile profile3;
private IProfile profile4;
private IProfile profile5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    // Handle Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_item_advanced_drawer);

    // Create a few sample profile
    profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile));
    profile2 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Max Muster").withEmail("max.mustermann@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile2)).withIdentifier(2);
    profile3 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Felix House").withEmail("felix.house@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile3));
    profile4 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mr. X").withEmail("mister.x.super@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile4)).withIdentifier(4);
    profile5 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Batman").withEmail("batman@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile5));

    // Create the AccountHeader
    buildHeader(false, savedInstanceState);

    //Create the drawer
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                    //here we use a customPrimaryDrawerItem we defined in our sample app
                    //this custom DrawerItem extends the PrimaryDrawerItem so it just overwrites some methods
                    new OverflowMenuDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_menu_drawer_item).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_menu_drawer_item_desc).withMenu(R.menu.fragment_menu).withOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            Toast.makeText(AdvancedActivity.this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_filter_center_focus),
                    new CustomPrimaryDrawerItem().withBackgroundRes(R.color.accent).withName(R.string.drawer_item_free_play).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_custom).withDescription("This is a description").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye),
                    new CustomUrlPrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_fragment_drawer).withDescription(R.string.drawer_item_fragment_drawer_desc).withIcon("https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1476232?v=3&s=460"),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_section_header),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cart_plus),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_help).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_database).withEnabled(false),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_open_source).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_contact).withSelectedIconColor(Color.RED).withIconTintingEnabled(true).withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_plus).actionBar().paddingDp(5).colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text)).withTag("Bullhorn"),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_help).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question).withEnabled(false)
            ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
            .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView) {
                    //this method is only called if the Arrow icon is shown. The hamburger is automatically managed by the MaterialDrawer
                    //if the back arrow is shown. close the activity
                    AdvancedActivity.this.finish();
                    //return true if we have consumed the event
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .addStickyDrawerItems(
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog).withIdentifier(10),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_open_source).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github)
            )
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();


}

/**
 * small helper method to reuse the logic to build the AccountHeader
 * this will be used to replace the header of the drawer with a compact/normal header
 *
 * @param compact
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
private void buildHeader(boolean compact, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create the AccountHeader
    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withCompactStyle(compact)
            .addProfiles(
                    profile,
                    profile2,
                    profile3,
                    profile4,
                    profile5,
                    //don't ask but google uses 14dp for the add account icon in gmail but 20dp for the normal icons (like manage account)
                    new ProfileSettingDrawerItem().withName("Add Account").withDescription("Add new GitHub Account").withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_plus).actionBar().paddingDp(5).colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text)).withIdentifier(PROFILE_SETTING),
                    new ProfileSettingDrawerItem().withName("Manage Account").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings)
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                    //sample usage of the onProfileChanged listener
                    //if the clicked item has the identifier 1 add a new profile ;)
                    if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == PROFILE_SETTING) {
                        IProfile newProfile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withNameShown(true).withName("Batman").withEmail("batman@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile5));
                        if (headerResult.getProfiles() != null) {
                            //we know that there are 2 setting elements. set the new profile above them ;)
                            headerResult.addProfile(newProfile, headerResult.getProfiles().size() - 2);
                        } else {
                            headerResult.addProfiles(newProfile);
                        }
                    }

                    //false if you have not consumed the event and it should close the drawer
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
}
```

[image: example]